# Python: Search for tkinter treeview record. How to jump to a tagged record after clicking search?

Tags: python-3.x, search, tkinter, tags, treeview

My table has hundreds of records and I need the table to scroll down automatically to the first tagged record.

This is what I have so far:

```
if model in prospects:
    found_rows.append(iid_count) # memorize iid of record in table

--------------------------------------------------

for foundrec in found_rows:
    all_table.item(foundrec, tags="Find_Green") 
#mark matching records green, where "found_rows" is a list of iids that match searching criteria
```

I would like the table to scroll down automatically to first highlighted row, not sure if that is possible.

Comment: `tree.see(iid)`

Comment: That works! Thank you!